# is 'FOR UPDATE' needed in SELECT statements when using SERIALIZABLE ISOLATION

Tags: sql, postgresql

say i have code like this in a SERIALIZABLE transaction:

```js
users =  "select * from users where account='x'"
for (u of users) {
 if (condition)
   "UPDATE users SET foo = 'bar' where id=u.id"
}
```

do i need to use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` instad of `SELECT`?

if yes, then what is the point of serializable isolation above? according to serializable isolation the current code should work fine.

if no, then what is the point of `SELECT FOR UPDATE`? is it only useful for lower isoaltion levels?

Comment: `SELECT FOR UPDATE` locks the record so that you don't have concurrency issues. Many RDBMS do not offer `SELECT FOR UPDATE` but provide other means of record locking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a functional point of view, there is no difference; the `SERIALIZABLE` level guarantees that the transaction is internally and externally consistent; however, from an operational point of view, there is a difference: the `FOR UPDATE` clause immediately locks the rows for any concurrent serializable transaction (and wait for any prior  locks if any) . Without it, it does not (most DBs nowadays including pg use snapshot reads to satisfy repeatable-read), but on the condition of an unserializable concurrency (always on a write), one of the transactions will be rolled back and will need to be retried.

So how is it different? Well let's assume your transaction takes 10 minutes to complete but you know beforehand which rows will be updated. Locking them in advance will make the 10 minute transaction wait for any locks before starting, eliminating the risk that it's rolled back aftre 5 minutes. Then it will lock out any concurrent transactions affecting the same rows until it finishes, instead of those transactions being possibly rolled back.

So, with judicious use of immediate locking semantics, one can reduce the amount of concurrency failures/rollbacks. On the other hand, indiscriminate use of immediate locking semantics (i.e. On rows that will not be affected) can kill concurrency.

To sum up, only in `SERIALIZABLE` mode:  functionally equal, operationally different, judicious use can be good, if in doubt don't use at all.

For lower isolation levels, `FOR UPDATE` is functionally relevant, as it allows i.e. snapshot concurrency to achieve serializability by way of explicit locking directions.